# Join SQL query to get data from two tables

Tags: sql, join

I'm a newbie, just learning SQL and have this question: I have two tables with the same columns. Some registers are in the two tables but others only are in one of the tables. To illustrate, suppose table A = (1,2,3,4), table B=(3,4,5,6), numbers are registers. I need to select all registers in table B if they are not in table A, that is result=(5,6). What query should I use? Maybe a join. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select register from TABLE_B b
Where not exists (Select register from TABLE_A a where a.register = b.register)
```

I assumed you have a column named register in TABLE_A and TABLE_B

Comment: logically i think it works, i will have to try with my tables with 1000+ registers... thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a NOT IN query like this:

`SELECT col from A where col not in (select col from B)`

or use an outer join:

`select A.col
from A LEFT OUTER JOIN B on A.col=B.col
where B.col is NULL`

The first is easier to understand, but the second is easier to use with more tables in the query.